# Navigation in uwp c#

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, frame

I'm trying to implement navigation between two UserControls. I do this: There is an AppController class, which has a ChangeCurrentView method, which is responsible for changing the UserControl in MainPage, but the method does not work:

```
internal class AppController {
  public enum CurrentViewTypes {
    NotesList,
    AddEditNote,
  }

  public void ChangeCurrentView(CurrentViewTypes viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
      case CurrentViewTypes.NotesList:
        NotesListViewModel sVM = new NotesListViewModel(this);
        NotesListView sV = new NotesListView();
        //привязка
        sV.DataContext = sVM;
        //отображение
        MainViewModel.CurrentView = sV;
        break;
      case CurrentViewTypes.AddEditNote:
        AddEditViewModel eVM = new AddEditViewModel(this);
        AddEditView eV = new AddEditView();
        //привязка
        eV.DataContext = eVM;
        //отображение
        MainViewModel.CurrentView = eV;
        break;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(viewType));
    }
  }
}
```

App launch in App.xaml.cs overridden like this:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
  MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
  mainPage.DataContext = _controller.MainViewModel;
  Window.Current.Content = mainPage;
  Window.Current.Activate();
  _controller.ChangeCurrentView(AppController.CurrentViewTypes.NotesList);
}
```

In MainPage.xaml this is the binding:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
```

[do it similar to this](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ExNavigationWpf/WpfApp1), [my code](https://github.com/JoJoBizarrio/NotesUwpTask/tree/Fetature_Correction)

I tried to do it by analogy with vpf cases (I used userControl with 1 page) but it doesn't work. How to implement navigation in uvp projects with mvvm architecture correctly? Do I need to use switching between user controls on 1 page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we use [Page Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page?view=winrt-22621) and [Frame Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame?view=winrt-22621) for navigation in UWP apps. Navigations happens between Pages vie Frame.Navigate method. UserControl is just a control which should be displayed inside a Page. ViewModels are used as the DataContext for the different Pages.

Also, you don't need to override the `onlaunch` method unless you want to change the start page. And if you want to change the start page, you just need to change the parameter of  `rootFrame.Navigate`.

I'd suggest you start with basic navigation in UWP here: [Implement navigation between two pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages).